# How to search a dict of unicode for a string

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, dictionary, utf-8

Using python 2.7.4 in Ubuntu 13.10 I'm having my head done in by string encodings.

I have a dict, d, of parts. This includes some unicode strings, eg:

```
[{'part_number': u'70-0018', 'name': 'Baseball caps', 'slug': u'70-0018', 'link': 'https://URL/index.php?path=info&part_uuid=13840f24-3819-11e2-9e3b-002564adbfd8'}, 
{'part_number': u'80-0002', 'name': 'Top Hats', 'slug': u'80-0002', 'link': 'https://URL/index.php?path=info&part_uuid=9ff5627e-3827-11e2-9e3b-002564adbfd8'}]
```

I would like to test for duplicate slugs as I'm creating the dict, and on a clash add a revision number to retain uniqueness:

```
for row in from_cur.fetchall():
  n = row[0]
  pt = row[1]
  pn = row[2]
  u = "https://URL/index.php?path=info&part_uuid="+row[3]  
  new_pn = u"%s-%s" %(pt,pn)
  sl = slugify(new_pn)

  if sl in parts:
    for i in range(10):
      new_sl = sl+"-%s" % str(i)
      if new_sl in parts:
        pass
      else:
        sl = new_sl
        break

  part = {"name":"%s" % n,"part_number":"%s" % new_pn, "link":"%s" % u, "slug":"%s" % sl}
  parts.append(part)
```

I have tried the "if sl in parts:" line with:

sl, unicode(sl), sl.encode('utf-8'), str(sl), sl.decode('ascii'), sl.decode('unicode-escape'), sl.decode('utf-8')

but none of them get me inside the if loop that changes the slug field.

How do I compare (or search for) a string with a unicode in a dict?

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing where `parts` is initially declared, but since you append dicts to it later I'm assuming it's a list of dicts. Possibly empty when you start. That kind of list membership test will not work. It's not a Unicode problem, it's a problem that you're testing to see if a string is in a list of dicts.

The best solution would be to maintain a set of used slugs as you go:

```
used_slugs = set()
for row in from_cur.fetchall():
    ...
    if sl in used_slugs:
        # do something to make a new slug
    ...
    used_slugs.add(sl)
    parts.append(part)
```

Comment: Yep, you got me. parts = [] is the declaration. Your soln was perfect - thanks.